# How to add custom checkbox before place order in Magento 2 in Pay by credit or debit card Payment Method

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, place-order, checkbox

How to add custom checkbox before place order button in Magento 2 in Pay by credit or debit card Payment Method (Take-payment).

And the checkbox is required so if any user not checked the checkbox the payment button is not working after checking that checkbox he payment is done

Any one has any idea how to do that.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I created Module for on my GitHub directory. not exact as per requirement but you can modify it as per your need or take reference

https://github.com/Rajesh-Gohil/Dropship

Note for community: added link because it's stable forever.

Comment: Thanks for your link will definitely check that if you found anything same please share with me.

Comment: If I found then will share surely....